# Woocommerce: how to display search results using the standard product/shop grid layout (archive page)?

Tags: wordpress, templates, search, woocommerce

Hej there!

I just did setup Woocommerce successfully in my custom template and everything is working fine — except for the **search results layout**. When I do perform a search through the **very own Woocommerce product search widget**, I end getting my results on the standard search results layout, instead of the archive page used for products by the shop plugin.

Category displaying is fine - it uses the archive page (shop grid), tags too, uses the archive page (shop grid). The only problem resides on the widget search results.

The search URL is fine as well... ?s=keyword&post_type=product

Thanks!
Cospefogo.

Comment: I am using the HOOKS method (instead of woocommerce.php way), as described here: https://docs.woothemes.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/

Answer (score 0):

Well... **Problem solved.**

After trying to narrow down the problem I did find the cause: I had a **obsolete function in my functions.php** used to force Wordpress to search on all custom post types, all taxonomies and relevant meta data fields.

This function had a not-dynamic list of targets for the search inside and the custom post type "product" was not present in the group. This is the reason why my search using the Woocommerce product finder widget was being altered.

I removed this problematic function and everything went back to normal.

Thanks for your attention!
Cospefogo.